# Get product from save event observer - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Following a product save event I am trying to access the product within Magento 2.

I have configured the listener on:

```
controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after
```

the xml looks as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
        <observer name="wire_products_update" instance="TBS\WireProductsHook\Observer\WireProductsUpdate" />
    </event>
</config>
```

When a product saved observers class is called.
But how to access the saved product information. The observer class is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
namespace TBS\WireProductsHook\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class WireProductsUpdate implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute( \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {

        // echos name of event: controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after
        echo 'name of event: ' . $observer->getEvent()->getName();

        // tried using the same method as the save class: <magento>/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php on line 76
        $controller = $observer->getData('controller');

        // Fails: Fatal error: Cannot access protected property ...
        $product = $controller->initializationHelper->initialize($controller->productBuilder->build($controller->getRequest()));

    }

}
```

Within **/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php** the event is fired on line 114:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after',
    ['controller' => $this]
);
```

Controller pass as an argument. However, I am unsure how to to use this to access the product.

I would like to get the products SKU

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to `$productobj` after saving product from backend then you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Put this `events.xml` in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And put your `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_sku=$_product->getSku(); // for sku

    }   
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's got it. Can I ask how I would find out about that event? I can't see it listed in the source code so didn't know it existed.

Comment: You can find reference of events from this links http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/ and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87738/magento-2-events-list @GuyC

Comment: I did have that list as a reference but couldn't see it there either, hence I ended up using: controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after, is it omitted for any reason?

Comment: Please note that if you put your event.xml file in adminhtml area then your observer will be not executed in other areas like REST or SOAP that represent web api

Comment: How to save the id to our custom able  from here

Comment: @GuyC Did you find why catalog_product_save_after is not in the events list? I have the same question.

Comment: @Mehdi been a while but at the time I didn't no. I assumed that the events list posted just wasn't very comprehensive, perhaps someone else can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @GuyC Finally found where it comes from. There is a specific event which uses an entity-specific “prefix”. In Magento, most of the core models redefine the internal variable “_eventPrefix”, so one can observe CRUD operations for specific models. To determine the prefix used for a model, you need to check the model source code. Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184772/magento-2-why-catalog-product-save-after-event-is-not-listed/184787

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old. I m not sure if anyone cares now. But I was looking for this so:

I m not sure since when but definitely on M2.2.x that event is like this now:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after',
                    ['controller' => $this, 'product' => $product]
                );
```

This means it is giving you now the product too.

For your case you should have done this and you could get the product attributes as an array:

```
$post = $observer->getController();
        $data = $post->getRequest()->getPost();
        $productAsArray = $data['product'];
```

Comment: $product = $observer->getData('product');

should get you the Product