# Get the existing product id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get the existing product id from my Model.

```
<?php

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    function __construct
    (
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $syncEngineFactory
    ) {
        $this->syncEngineFactory = $syncEngineFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $this->productUpdate($product);
        return $this;

   public function productUpdate($product){
     $productId = 1;
     $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\ResourceModel\Queue')->load($productId,'entity_id');   //Erro here   'Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::load()
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Event is : catalog_product_save_after

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can load product collection by below code:

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    $_product = $observer->getProduct()->getId();  // you will get product object
    $_sku=$_product->getSku(); // for sku

 }
```

**Complete Answer:**

Create events.xml file in \module\etc\adminhtml\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer file in Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php

```
<?php

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    function __construct
    (
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $syncEngineFactory
    ) {
        $this->syncEngineFactory = $syncEngineFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $this->productUpdate($product);
        return $this;

   public function productUpdate($product){
     //$productId = 1;
     $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\ResourceModel\Queue')->load($product,'entity_id');   //Erro here   'Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::load()
    }
}
```

Reference : [Get product from save event observer - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2)

Comment: tried that..but i want to get the existing product id...

Comment: for which event you have created this observer? post event name anyone can guide on that direction.

Comment: its catalog_product_save_after event, i want to get the id during the product save

Comment: have you tried this `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();`

Comment: Check the updated execute() @Sarfaraz...im unable to get the product id using the load() as above , i get the erro

Comment: Updated answer use that code to get product id

Comment: I want to get only the current product id, not the collection @Sarfaraz...I wan to get it dynamically, not by assigning some static values

Comment: i get Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::load() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel, string given in my load() @Sarfaraz