# Magento 2: Why catalog_product_save_after event is not listed?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

On manually saving products on the admin page, I have tested the `catalog_product_save_after` event and my observer can successfully catch the event. So this event exists in Magento 2, however I can not find this event in any cheat sheets like: https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

On the other hand, I can find `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` in the list.

So here is my question: why `catalog_product_save_after` event is not listed? What is the difference between `catalog_product_save_after` and `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2.1.7 CE:

1) `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` is trigger when saving product in Admin.

2) Most Model entities derive from `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`. In this abstract class, we can find some events. For example:

```
/**
 * Processing object after save data
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function afterSave()
{
    ......
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    ......
}
```

As we can see, some model events names will be trigger. The name of event will be added the prefix `$this->_eventPrefix`of model. We can define the event prefix in the model.

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php*

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalog_product';
```