# Magento2 Change Sku of product with custom option

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

> I have simple product with SKU :  AAA

and has custom options Sku 
**Option 1**

```
A1A1A1
A2A2A2
```

**Option 2**

```
B1B1B1
B2B2B2
```

On Product page SKU is showing `AAA` is fine.
Now if customer Add to cart and chosse first option in both sectios for this product it's SKu Bocomes `AAA-A1A1A1-B1B1B1` in cart and Order

I want to change it's saperator from **-** to **+** 
so result SKU becomes `AAA+A1A1A1+B1B1B1`
How can  ido it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below which have event for product save after, it means when we save products than get sku and than set sku.

[Get product from save event observer - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2)

I hope, its working fine for you. :)

Comment: no problem on product SKU it is fine, i want to change in quote and order SKu which is concate options sku with current