# Fire event observer when product is enabled

Tags: admin, event-observer

I want to fire event observer when products are enabled from admin, I can not find any event for this please help on this.

**I want to do below things**

1. Once the product is enabled or disabled need to mail admin.
2. I want to do it from the Observer or any other method.

Please help!

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making a call on product save you can create a plugin to call it on product save.

For that, you have to add code in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save">
    <plugin name="supplier_plugin_product_save_after" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Adminhtml\ProductSave" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And in ProductSave.php file in Plugin/Adminhtml and add the code as per your need in code given below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ProductSave
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        RequestInterface $request,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param Save $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterExecute(Save $subject, $result)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        $productId = $product->getId();

        $params = $this->request->getParams();

        /****  ADD YOUR LOGIC HERE ****/
    }
}
```