# Magento 2: Why this event is not working for me? prepare_catalog_product_index_select

Tags: magento2

Magento version: 2.0

events.xml

```
<event name="prepare_catalog_product_index_select">
        <observer name="list_product_observer" instance="Demo\Product\Observer\ListProductObserver" />
    </event>
```

ListProductObserver.php

```
class ListProductObserver implements ObserverInterface
{   
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = array(
            'product' => $productId,
            'user'  => $userId,
            'value' => 333
        );
        $myfile = fopen("/file_path/ListProductObserver.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($data, true));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

I create a function to do some when admin user enter the catalog list page.
But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'd check next cases:
1. Be sure that event "prepare_catalog_product_index_select" is dispatched.
2. Verify that your observer is in list of the event observers. Need to debug code in \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager::dispatch
3. Verify that your observer is invoked.

Comment: @ArkadiiChyzhov do you have the full list of events? do you tell me where i can find them?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87738/magento-2-events-list?rq=1

Comment: @ArkadiiChyzhov 1, this event is in the list of url you recommend below. 2, I tried to check whether it is in the event list, but i can get the error or correct message on \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager::dispatch. do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the instance of "**ListProductObserver**" in events.xml, but you named the class as "**ListOwnerProductObserver**"

Comment: thanks for your reply. i made a typo and correct it just now. but it doesn't work for me. I guess the event name is wrong. i don't know which name is correct.