# What's the best event/way to listen for all order state changes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, sales-order, order-status

I want to observe every order state change and react depending on the old and new status. What is the best way to accomplish this in Magento 2?

It looks like there is the event `sales_order_state_change_before` but unfortunately it does not seem to fire on state changes. There is also a considerable list of other events which fire in some cases of order changes:
`sales_order_invoice_pay`
`sales_order_payment_place_end`
`sales_order_payment_capture`
`sales_order_payment_pay`
... just to name a few.

However I'm not exactly sure when which of above events fire and it definitely looks like they only fire in very special occasions. But I need a way which guaranteed covers **all state changes** and allows me to query the old and new status. 
What is the best way to achieve this, am I missing an event or is there a better way than registering an observer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, we can use events: `sales_order_save_after` and `sales_order_state_change_before`. I refer `sales_order_save_after` event.

In our observer, we can get the state of order:

**Observer/SalesOrderAfterSave.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
       if($order->getState() == 'canceled' || $order->getState() == 'closed') {
            //Your code here
       }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

We can read more about observer : [Magento 2 events list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87738/magento-2-events-list)

**NOTE:** **We should try with Plugin**:

*etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Plugin:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $result
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {
    if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        ......
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is better than the events I knew of so far but it is not firing when the customer creates the order with an initial "pending" state. I'm not sure if there are more cases where it is not triggered.
By the way, do you know of a complete Magento 2 event list? Mine seems incomplete.

Comment: Regarding the list, there is already a topic: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87738/magento-2-events-list

Comment: As far as I know, by default, Magento doesn't have `pending` state, it's a status. There are some default states: `new, pending_payment, processing, complete, closed, canceled, holded, payment_review`. We should take a look `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php`

Comment: You are completely right, the state I was referring to is `new` ("Pending" is what it says in the Backend). And I'm still having a hard time to react to newly placed orders by customers. `sales_order_place_after` is not firing and all my other attempts aren't as well. One should guess this is a basic task :/

Comment: Okay so that was really my bad. I forgot the different XML hierarchy in Magento 2 and my `events.xml` was still placed in `/etc/adminhtml/` of my module. Moving it to `/etc/` worked. Now `sales_order_save_after` also fires when customers create orders. And from my short testing now with other here mentioned events it is better in the sense that it provides more information about the order.  `sales_order_place_after` for example doesn't know of the order's ID yet. So `sales_order_save_after` really seems to be the event I was looking for!

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh how can I get the orders old and new data and get the difference in my custom table?

Comment: How to use around function here?

Comment: Shouldn't we try to plugin afterSetState? afterSave will call on after every order change, Isn't it so much calling? @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: But how will you get the old value of the status using sales_order_save_after event?