# Which event should I catch if I want a "complete" order?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.0

I'm new at Magento's module developing. I'm trying to get data from orders when their status changes to "complete". Acording to [this](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/manage-order-status-in-magento-2/) tutorial, orders are complete after shipment. The way I found to do this is catching an event with an observer and, with the observer, send the data. The thing is I'm not really sure which event should I be catching. I checked this [list](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) looking for the right event, but I'm still not sure. **Does anyone knows which event should I be looking for?** Is there an easier way to do what I want?

Comment: You can read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me you should use `sales_order_state_change_before` with an extra condition in your observer: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.7/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php#L242

In your observer you will have to get the transport object from the event first:

```
$transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
```

Then check that this object state is equal to complete:

```
if ($transport->getState() == "complete")
```

NB: you can get the order with the following code:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```