# Magento2 Observer - Order Complete

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer

What event would I want to observe for when an order is set to 'complete' in the back end?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2/125063#125063

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use event **sales_order_save_after** for your query

In observer, you can get the state of order using condition complete,

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
           if($order->getState() == 'complete') {
                //Your code after completer state goes to here
           }
 }
```