# Magento 2 : How to get Order completed time?

Tags: orders, magento-2.1.7

I am able to get order details by **Order ID**, but it is giving `created_time` and `updated_time`.

Is there anyway to get order complete time?

Answer (score 2):

As per I know by default in `Magento` does not provide the order completed time. `created_time` change only once during order creation and `updated_time`change on every order action (i.e shipment, Invoice, order status change etc) so you can not predict the exact time for order complete.

But you can create one custom attribute to order level as `completed_time` and you can update this value by using  plugin. In this plugin you can get the order state. Just compare the order state, If it is `complete` then update your custom variable.

For the plugin you can read answer from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125063/2589)