# Catch event: sales order status change

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status

I am creating a module where I am adding an observer to the event `sales_order_save_after` which checks the order status and then sends an invoice e-mail.
However, the event is only valid if the order is saved, e.g. create a shipment. This is not what I need.

Is there an event to catch an **order status** change (the order status is changed from *processing* to *complete* after an API push call).

**current events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name='sales_order_save_after'>
        <observer name='vendor_autoinvoice_send_invoice' instance='Vendor\AutoInvoice\Model\Observer\AutoInvoice'/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Similar answer you are lookig for is at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2 . It may help you.

Comment: I was aware of these but they are all related to order state changes, not order status.

Comment: Magento 2 is strict with `state`. And all `status` types follow `state`. Here you can check for `status` value as per need.