# getting Order status between two state

Tags: magento2, magento-1.8, order-status

I have a problem in getting the sum of time taken between two status of an order

I can able the get the created time by the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'complete'))
    ->load()
```

is there a way to get the sum of time taken between two status like sum(OrderInvoiced+OrderShipped) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2

You will need to save time in your custom table. Then you will be able to get the sum of time

Comment: I belive all the order status and  created_at time are stored in this table sales_order_status_history is there a way to sum up with this information

Answer (score 1):

You can check these details in this table **sales_flat_order_status_history**.

```
//Load order object using the order ID
$order->getStatusHistoryCollection(); // This will give all the status associated with the order
```

Find the time difference between first status and complete status will be the time taken to fulfill the order.

A minimum calculation in PHP will give you the time difference

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2012-06-01 02:12:51');
$date2 = $date1->diff(new DateTime('2014-05-12 11:10:00'));
echo $date2->days.'days';
echo $date2->h.' hours'."\n";
```

Comment: Its helpful thank you