# Magento 2 - Order status update observer

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, order-status, status

I am looking for order status update observer

In many post I have found this one:

```
sales_order_save_after
```

But, it is not working, I have checked it myself. It is not even listed in these articles:
https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-events-list/
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Please help, which observer should I use? I need to do something when order status updated.

Thanks

Comment: When do you want to update the status?

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2) will help you.

Comment: I had tried `sales_order_save_after` before, but it wasn't triggering my observer