# Magento 2.3, Get the order status before and after change using the plugin?

Tags: magento2.3, plugin, order-status

In Magento 2.3, How to get order statuses, before and after change using the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue.

1. In `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order">
     <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
         type="Vendor\YourModule\Plugin\NameForYourPlugin"/>
</type>
```

2. In `NameForYourPlugin` File:

```
    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
         $result,$object
    ){
        $oldData = $object->getOrigData('status');
        $newData = $object->getData('status');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin on Class `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order`.

Create plugin on `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::save()`

Here, I have used after the plugin.

See more details about After plugin Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods

#### Code

```
<?php 
namespace StackExchanges\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel;

class Order
{

    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
        $result,
        $object
    ) {
        $oldData = $object;
        $oldStatus = $object->getStatus();
        $newData = $result;
        $newsStatus = $newData->getStatus();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera. I will check it.

Comment: It is afterSave or aroundSave?

Comment: It is Aftersave .,..

Comment: I tried the solution, I am getting this error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Interceptor::getStatus() in root\app\code\Namesapace\Module\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin.php:31

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: okay, I will look into it

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this?

Comment: sorry, i forgot, but i will check at will confirm u

Comment: Okay. I tried this too. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125063/35778

Answer (score 1):

Use beforeSave plugin for order model, with below two methods

old value: `$order->getOrigData('status');`

new value: `$order->getData('status');`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @YashPatadia, What will be the plugin class?

Comment: Magento\Sales\Model\Order

Comment: Okay I will check and let you know.

Comment: Yes it is worked. But used `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order` plugin class instead `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

Comment: Great :) ......