# How to get order data before and after save in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders

In Magento 2, How to get order data(before and after save) using plugin function. I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303454/magento-2-3-get-the-order-status-before-and-after-change-using-the-plugin) solution but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Order data after save using following way:

> /app/code/vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order">
        <plugin name="after_place_order_save" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Order.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Order
{
    /**
     * [afterSave description]
     * @param  \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject [description]
     * @param  [type]                                   $result  [description]
     * @param  [type]                                   $object  [description]
     * @return [type]                                            [description]
     */
    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
        $result,
        $object
    ) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Order_data.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(print_r($object->getIncrementId(), true));
        $logger->info(print_r($object->getId(), true));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: I need both data before and after saving in the same function using around plugin.