# Which Plugin or Observer will work perfect at the time of Saving Order data in sales_order table Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, plugin, grand-total, subtotal

> I am trying to know that which plugin or observer will work perfectly
>   while saving order data in sales_order table. Actually i am trying to
>   debug a scenario where only for one order, **Grand Total < SubTotal** in Admin Order Grid.
>   Means it's mysteriously discounted an Order without applying a coupon.
>
> This case only for one order from >1000 orders but not able to
>   reproduce this issue once again until it will not reproduce.

If any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a detailed stuff, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303454/magento-2-3-get-the-order-status-before-and-after-change-using-the-plugin/304146#304146

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any third-party extension which provides custom discount then obviously.

there are two way Cart Price Rule rules on cart items. One is a coupon and another is  **No Coupon**. See detail https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-create.html#step-2-describe-the-conditions

I guess that Cart Price rules can be automatically applied to your cart item. In order to debug the rules, disable all `Cart Price Rule rules` which is NO Coupon.

Comment: okay i will check and update you. Thanks for answer.

Comment: All Cart Price Rules are with Coupon only. There is no rule without coupon.