# How to create a plugin to track order status change in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have to create a plugin to track if the order status changes and then trigger notification after that

Comment: Please check this post with an answer if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304178/68003

Answer (score 1):

You can create After plugin for

> Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class OrderSave
{

    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
        $result,
        $object
    ) {
        $oldStatusOrder = $object->getStatus();
        
        $newsStatusOrder = $result->getStatus();
        // do your stuff


        return $result;
    }
}
```