# magento 2 - different email template based on order status

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, magento2.4.2

I have multiple status like

```
1: Pending 
2: Processing
3: cancelled
4: completed
```

When order is cancelled used get defualt status notification email, instead i want to use different template when order status is canclled.

Please help me with way to do same, i am bit new in magento , will observer help ? please help way out

Comment: If you want to do this with extension then you can use this: https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-custom-order-status.html

Comment: Otherwise, this can help if you want to do this by event: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass new variables via Observer to use in the email template using knockout {{if}} to show some parts of email template...

**In your observer add conditions to pass the variable depending the status**

```
 $orderData = $transport->getData('order');
```

I assume based in your order Data can add some conditions to pass the variable you need to use in the email Template.

```
if(//Here you search for the status in the order){

    $transport['processing'] = 'processing';}else{
    
    $transport['Pending'] = 'Pending';}
```

1.- Inside your admin Marketing > Email Templates.
Create a new template. Then add the condition to show which part of the template need to display in the email.

```
 <!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
    <!--@vars {
    "var order.getBillingAddress().getName()":"Guest Customer Name",
    "var store.getFrontendName()":"Customer Name",
    "var is_pickup_order":"Check if order is a pickup order",
    "var store_email |raw":"Defined Email Address for this type of mails",
    "var store_phone |raw":"Defined Phone Number in the Store Information",
    "var store_hours |raw":"Defined Opening Hours Phone Number in the Store Information",
    "var order.increment_id |raw":"Order Id",
    "var order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw":"Get the date of order creation",
    "var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
    "var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
    "var order.getIsNotVirtual()":"Check if shipment exists",
    "var pickupAddress|raw":"Pickup Location Address",
    "var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Customer Shipping Address",
    "var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
    "var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
    "var shipping_msg":"Shipping message",
    "layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid"
    } @-->
{{if processing}} 
        
    
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
    
    <table>
        <tr class="email-intro">
            <td>
                <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}</p>
                <p>
                    {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                    {{if is_pickup_order}}
                        {{trans "We will send you a notification once your items are ready for pickup."}}
                    {{else}}
                        {{trans "Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order."}}
                    {{/if}}
                    {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans ' or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                    {{depend store_hours}}
                        {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                    {{/depend}}
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-summary">
            <td>
                <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
                <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-information">
            <td>
                {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
                <table class="message-info">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {{/depend}}
                <table class="order-details">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="address-details">
                            <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                            <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                        </td>
                        {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                        <td class="address-details">
                            <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                            {{if is_pickup_order}}
                                <h4>{{trans "Pickup Location"}}</h4>
                                <p>{{var pickupAddress|raw}}</p>
                                <h4>{{trans "Recipient Address"}}</h4>
                            {{/if}}
                            <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                        </td>
                        {{/depend}}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="method-info">
                            <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                            {{var payment_html|raw}}
                        </td>
                        {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                        <td class="method-info">
                            <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                            <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                            {{if shipping_msg}}
                            <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                            {{/if}}
                        </td>
                        {{/depend}}
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

    {{/if}}

    {{if completed}} 
        /// Your custom email template and its variables here
    {{/if}}
```

... etc.

if the variable has text it will be considered as true an use the part inside of the email template you need...
Also no need to declare the var inside @vars. your observer will pass it without problem

This could be a fast solution. Another should be create a new module EmailSystem to define the template to use depending the case...